# GKE randomly dropping connections

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

We're running a Kubernetes cluster on GKE, with an NGINX ingress controller (so that we can accept WS connections), and a network load balancer connected to it through a service to make it accessible from the internet.

Everything works perfectly fine **most of the time**. But we get "connection refused" at seemingly random intervals.

Looking at the logs, it seems as if the dropped requests never hit NGINX (NGINX doesn't log anything at all for these requests). We've tried recreating the external load balancer, the service and so on but without success. Not sure where to go from here or where the issue lies.

Does anyone recognise the problem? Or have any potential solution? Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Can you share more details? Especially about the way you monitor/experience this and the network details. Is it just monitoring->LB->Node pool->Nginx Ingress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new cluster? Strange things might happen sometimes in the world of GKE

Comment: Only thing that seemed to work. Very strange, but no problems after creating a new cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if all kube-proxy pods in your cluster are functioning correctly? Use the following command:

```
kubectl get --namespace=kube-system pod -l component=kube-proxy  -o wide
```

Maybe some of the kube-proxy is not functioning properly. Hence causing intermittent connection problem.

Comment: This is a start, it does show that pod was restarted, but there are no logs.